# Keras.layers.concatenate generates an error'

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a CNN with two input branches. And these two branches (b1, b2) are to be merged into a densely connected layer of 256 neurons with dropout rate of 0.25. This is what I have so far:

```
batch_size, epochs = 32, 3
ksize = 2
l2_lambda = 0.0001


### My first model(b1)
b1 = Sequential()
b1.add(Conv1D(128*2, kernel_size=ksize,
             activation='relu',
             input_shape=( xtest.shape[1], xtest.shape[2]),
             kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda)))
b1.add(Conv1D(128*2, kernel_size=ksize, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda)))
b1.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=ksize))
b1.add(Dropout(0.2))

b1.add(Conv1D(128*2, kernel_size=ksize, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda)))
b1.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=ksize))
b1.add(Dropout(0.2))

b1.add(Flatten())

###My second model (b2)

b2 = Sequential()
b2.add(Dense(64, input_shape = (5000,), activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda)))
b2.add(Dropout(0.1))


##Merging the two models
model = Sequential()
model.add(concatenate([b1, b2],axis = -1))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

**But when I concatenate it gives me the following error:**

[image]

I first tried using the following command:

```
  model.add(Merge([b1, b2], mode = 'concat'))
```

But I got the error that **'ImportError: cannot import name 'Merge''**. I am using keras 2.2.2 and python 3.6.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too but I got the same error as before. And I am not sure how to change it to functional API. I am new to Keras and machine learning.

Comment: Aha! Use `b1.output` and `b2.output` instead of `b1` and `b2`.

Comment: I just tried it and I got the following error now:  **TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor("concatenate_1/concat:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32)**

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help. But xtest.shape[1] is 5000 and xtest.shape[2] is 208.

Comment: Sorry! My initial comment was a bit wrong (as a result I deleted it to prevent further confusion). Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) to achieve what you are looking for. You can either use `Concatenate` layer or its equivalent functional API `concatenate`:

```
concat = Concatenate(axis=-1)([b1.output, b2.output])
# or you can use the functional api as follows:
#concat = concatenate([b1.output, b2.output], axis=-1)

x = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal',
          kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda))(concat)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
output = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model([b1.input, b2.input], [output])
```

Note that I have only converted the last part of your model to functional form. You can do the same thing for the other two models `b1` and `b2` (actually, it seems that the architecture you are trying to define is one single model that consists of two branches that are merged together). At the end, use `model.summary()` to see and recheck the architecture of the model.

Comment: Thank you. My network works fine now. You saved the day for me :)