# Python Keras Multiple Input Layers - How to Concatenate/Merge?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, concatenation, lstm

In python, I am trying to build a neural network model using Sequential in keras to perform binary classification. Note that X is a numpy array of time series data 59x1000x3 (samples x timesteps x features) and D is a numpy array of 59x100 (samples x auxillary features). I want to pass the time series through an lstm layer, and then augment at a later layer with the accompanying features (i.e. concatenate two layers).

My code to fit the model is below:

```
def fit_model(X, y, D, neurons, batch_size, nb_epoch):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units = neurons, input_shape = (X.shape[1], X.shape[2]))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Dense(10))
    input1 = Sequential()
    d = K.variable(D)
    d_input = Input(tensor=d)
    input1.add(InputLayer(input_tensor=d_input))
    input1.add(Dropout(0.1))
    input1.add(Dense(10))
    final_model = Sequential()
    merged = Concatenate([model, input1])
    final_model.add(merged)
    final_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    final_model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam')
    final_model.fit(X, y, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = nb_epoch)
    return final_model
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs

I tried using various permutations of merge/concatenate/the functional api/not the functional api, but I keep landing with some sort of error. I've seen answers using Merge from keras.engine.topology. However, it seems to now be deprecated. Any suggestions to fix the error when using Sequential or how to convert the code to the functional API would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try using `concatenate` with c in lower case. you can find more about this here [https://keras.io/layers/merge/#concatenate_1]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keras.layers.concatenate generates an error'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328130/keras-layers-concatenate-generates-an-error)

Comment: Please switch to keras functional API. It's much easier to realize your use case this way. Sequential model is only meant for very simple models which only have one input and one output.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I re-wrote my code to use concatenate with the keras functional API and that works.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly passing a Model and an Input as parameters of the Concatenate layer:

```py
merged = Concatenate([model, input1])
```

Try passing another Input layer instead:

```py
merged = Concatenate([input1, input2])
```